# Product of distribution of independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, tensor-products, independence

Suppose that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent random variables defined in some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,P)$. 
Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb R$ is Borel measurable.

I think that is true that
$$
\bigotimes_{i=1}^n (P\circ X_i^{-1})(f^{-1}(A))=P(f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\in A),
$$ 
for all $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)$. 
Can you give a hint to prove that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The independence tells us that:$$P\circ\left(X_{1},\dots,X_{n}\right)^{-1}=\bigotimes_{i=1}^{n}P\circ X_{i}^{-1}$$

Then:

$\begin{aligned}\left(\bigotimes_{i=1}^{n}P\circ X_{i}^{-1}\right)\left(f^{-1}\left(A\right)\right) & =\left(P\circ\left(X_{1},\dots,X_{n}\right)^{-1}\right)\left(f^{-1}\left(A\right)\right)\\
 & =\left(P\circ\left(X_{1},\dots,X_{n}\right)^{-1}\circ f^{-1}\right)\left(A\right)\\
 & =\left(P\circ\left(f\left(X_{1},\dots,X_{n}\right)\right)^{-1}\right)\left(A\right)\\
 & =P\left(f\left(X_{1},\dots,X_{n}\right)\in A\right)
\end{aligned}
$